# Is every fundamental force a bend or a wave in some kind of field?

Tags: field-theory

Gravitational force is a bend in the space-time fabric.....so I would like to know that is every other **fundamental force** is a bend or a wave in some kind of field/s?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76354/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111784/50583

Answer (score 1):

The current theoretical description of gravity is general relativity in which the curvature of spacetime influences the motion of particles. The other three fundamental forces are described by quantum field theories. Gravity can't (currently) be explained in the same way the other forces can, that will require a quantum theory of gravity which we don't have.

It's worth also noting that just because in general relativity we talk about spacetime "curving" doesn't mean there is some strange fabric that permeates the universe and physically bends. It is a purely mathematical model that happens to predict the behaviour of what we call gravity.

Comment: So are they waves in those quantum fields?

Comment: In quantum field theory yes. [Gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) also exist but they are not central to how gravity manifests in the theory.

Answer (score 1):

Only something to add to the existing [answer from Charlie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/538084/179151) . Any interaction except gravity is carried by the interaction - carrier particle ( photons for electromagnetism , gluons for strong interaction , Z and W bosons for weak interaction ).